# SSDT/SSRS - Report Previewer Won't Run

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I'm having a very peculiar issue with SQL Server Data Tools 2012. Whenever I attempt to launch the report previewer, I get the following exception:

> There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/PreviewProcessingServce7324/ReportProcessing that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more deatils.

[image: Error Message]

As far as I can tell, nothing I did triggered the issue. It just started happening one day when I fired up SSDT. I tried the suggestion on 
[Report Designer Preview in SSDT throws up a 'end point' not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH1pA.png).

However, my service is up and running just fine (restarting it didn't help), and using Setspn didn't do anything for it, either.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Thanks and I wondering if you have to use SQL Server Data Tools 2012 because SQL Server Data Tools 2010 that comes with SQL server works fine when previewing reports. I have both installed!

Comment: Yeah, I did have 2012. I was working with SQL Server 2014, and wanted to be closer in version numbers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is a current bug in SSDT-BI. The current workaround for now is to right click on the report you want to preview in your Solution Explorer and click RUN.

You will also notice that if you try to preview the report for the first time a command prompt window opens up that runs the preview process, If you don't close this window and just minimize it then you can preview the report but I think the RUN method is much easier for now. Please mark as answer if this helped.

Answer (score 4):

This can happen when you have some SQL Services installed and running on your machine that interfere with the Report Preview. You can check your current services by going opening Sql Server Configuration Manager:

[image: Sql Server Configuration Manager]

To **fix** this you can [do the following](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/38ff8d54-06aa-40c3-8916-378d5185320e/report-designer-preview-in-ssdt-throws-up-a-end-point-not-found-error?forum=sqlreportingservices):

1. Type <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>,  input `services.msc` in the Run box, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Find the "Net.Pipe Listener Adapter" and either Restart or Disable it.
   [image: Net.Pipe Listener Adapter - Services]

The **workaround**, as SQLnbe mentioned, is to:

1. Right Click the RDLC file from solution explorer
2. Click "Run" from there which will open up a new window.
   [image: Run RDLC from Solution Explorer]

Answer (score 3):

The Preview issue was resolved for me when I deleted the .DATA files associated with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried all the above solutions, and:

1. "Run" from context menu does not really work for me, as it's much, much longer than preview in VS2017, as rendering was a deciding factor in my work (lots of grouping by column etc). and render is much faster in VS compared to SSRS,
2. Could not find listed .Net services on my laptop,
3. Deleting DATA files did not fixed the issue either,
4. VS restart and reloading the solution.

I'm not sure if it was points 3 and 4 together that actually did the trick, but I'm putting it out there - just in case it actually is the procedure that will work for others, which is to try option 4.

I need to also note that this issue started after there was a momentary connection dropout. I need to work with WIFI instead LAN due to necessity to be roam-able, and every time I undock the laptop all my connections in SSMS are lost (and with them all the temp tables etc).

Answer (score 0):

### I faced the same issue and solved it.

**Steps:**

---

1. Right click on the report.

---

2. Click **view code**.

---

3. Check the **parameters** names in both **query** parameters and **report** parameters and make sure it's written correctly.

---

4. Close the report and open it again

---

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

1. Restart the .Net.Pipe service in the service console. This didn't resolve the issues.
2. Closed Visual Studio completely and relaunch the Visual Studio 2017 (in my case).

It seem that the preview is back. It could be the combination of (1) and (2).

Answer (score 0):

None of the solution above worked for me. What did I found and it worked is to run Visual Studio as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Just closing the visual Studio by ending task with task manager and re-opening the solution worked for me to get through the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).